# How can I import attribute values?

Tags: magento, import, attributes

I am using Magento and I have created an attribute manufacturer. I want to import values for this attribute but not one by one.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can help you.

Comment: I Am trying to follow this steps but i have problems on creating modules

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054486/add-new-values-to-a-attribute-option-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$arg_attribute = 'manufacturer';
$manufacturers = array('Sony','Philips','Samsung');

$attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
$attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();

$option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
foreach ($manufacturers as $key=>$manufacturer) {
    $option['value'][$manufacturer][0] = $manufacturer;
}
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttributeOption($option);
```